# SQLAlchemy: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have `database.py` which contains the database exec functions

```
import sqlachemy

class DB():
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.connection = None
    self.connect(**kwargs)

def connect(self, **kwargs):
    if 'url' in kwargs and kwargs.get('url') is not None:
        return self.connectUrl(kwargs.get('url'), kwargs.get('username'), 
            kwargs.get('password'), kwargs.get('database'))
    else : 
        return self.connectHost(kwargs.get('host'), kwargs.get('port'), kwargs.get('username'), 
            kwargs.get('password'), kwargs.get('database'))

def execute(self, query):
    if self.connect is None:
        raise Exception('No connection')

    try:
        with self.connection.connect() as conn:
            return conn.execute(query)
    except (pymysql.err.OperationalError, sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError) as e:
        print(e)
    except (Exception) as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        return None
```

Also I've a  `main.py`. Im importing the DB class from the above file and using it here.

```
from database import db
# db connection
def connect():
   global db
   db = DB(
    database="DATABASE_NAME",
    username="DATABASE_USER",
    password="XXXXXXXXX",
    url="XXXXXXX",
    host="XXXXXXXXXXX",
    port="XXXXXXX",
    )

SQL_QUERY = """ select * from sample_table where country = :country and age = :age """

_age = 5
_country = 'US'
 
connect()
query = text(SQL_QUERY).bindparams(bindparam("country", String), bindparam("age", String))
db.execute(query, age=_age, country=_country)
```

When I'm trying to execute this script, I'm getting an error

```
db.execute(query,age=_age, country=_country) TypeError: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'age'
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: how come you don't get an error for "SQL = ...." . you can't have sql like that in python

Comment: @eshirvana it was a mistake. I have edited the question. Pls have a look.

Answer (score 5):

The `execute()` function requires (named) params to be passed as a `dict`:

```
with db.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(statement=query, parameters=dict(_age=5, _country='US'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply pass variables as tuple :

```
query = 'select * from sample_table where country = ? and age = ?'
_age = 5
_country = 'US'
 
connect()

db.execute(query, (_age,_country,))
```